# bundle install fails trying to build json 1.4.6 - which I'm not referencing

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to run bundle install on a ruby project and it fails with the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/chrismc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150317-85350-hx8dcj.rb extconf.rb
checking for re.h... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling parser.c
parser.rl:165:20: error: expected '(' after 'if'
                if RTEST(rb_funcall(klass, i_json_creatable_p, 0)) {
                   ^
/Users/chrismc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:437:18: note: expanded from macro 'RTEST'
#define RTEST(v) !(((VALUE)(v) & ~Qnil) == 0)
                 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/json-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/json-1.4.6/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.4.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using rvm and I've tried this on several different versions of Ruby with similar results.

**I am not referencing json 1.4.6 anywhere in my project.**

It is unclear to me why bundler is even trying to install this gem, much less how to resolve the issue. I am likewise unable to install the gem using "gem install."

My OS is Mac OSX.

The output of gem env is as follows:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/chrismc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/chrismc/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/chrismc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: Is `json` anywhere in your Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, such as it is, is that the chefspec gem is indirectly requiring json 1.4.6. It happens that I don't need chefspec in this code so I was simply able to remove the reference and go on about my business.

I do not have an answer for how to actually use chefspec if I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

Something looks wrong with your compiler setup, and also you're using an outdated Ruby version.

The parser file should not have that error, and it is unlikely (IMHO) to be specifically because of your Ruby version, or to JSON. It is more likely you're trying to compile with incorrect compiler.

Are you able to install the pure JSON gem?

```
gem install json-pure
```

Are you able to install the current JSON native gem?

```
gem install json -v "1.8.2"
```

If you are able to install both:

- Then the next place to look is what's forcing the older json gem.
- Read your Gemfile.lock, and look for the older json gem.
- Also, ideally update everything in your Gemfile to be current e.g. change anything that is pinned to a version such as `gem 'foo', '~>x.y.z'` to `gem 'foo', '>= x.y.z'` then run `bundle update` to discover what happens. You may need to revert the Gemfile later on, if gem versions are incompatible with your own codebase.

If you are able to install the pure gem, but not the current native gem:

- Then the next place to check is your compiler.

Are you able to install current Ruby?

```
rvm install ruby --latest
```

If so, does that solve the JSON issue?

Where is your GCC?

```
command -v gcc
```

What version is it?

```
gcc --version
Configured with:
--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Your error message says that results are logged to this file:

```
/Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/json-1.4.6/gem_make.out`
```

Can you post that entire file?

(If you're concerned about the file having semi-private info, feel free to post it somewhere private or email it; I am "joelparkerhenderson" on GitHub, Google, etc.)

Comment: With ruby 2.1.0 I was able to do all of those things successfully. I switched over to ruby 2.2.0 and bundle install worked. However, I'm sure I tried 2.2.0 before and it did not work. I suspect that my trial and error attempts have distorted my environment and I won't know what I did to fix the problem. I'll try this on another machine soon and see if I can recreate the problem or if the answer is just migrate to 2.2.0. FWIW, it's still baffling that this is a problem in 2.1.0.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your environment seems to be distored. Although it may be due to something beyond what you've done. For example, other system software may have upgraded, such as the compiler, or OSX, or brew, etc. The `gem_make.out` file may illuminate this.

Comment: I removed Gemfile.lock and re-executed bundle install and it's now failing on ruby 2.2.0.  I don't seem to be able to format comments as well, so I'll respond to your questions in separate comments so that it shows up well.

Comment: I installed the latest ruby successfully using rvm. Ruby version is listed as ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

Comment: gcc is located in /usr/bin/gcc

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: For ruby 2.2.0p0 the error building json-1.4.6 is different:

Comment: Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /Users/chrismc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/json-1.4.6/CHANGES
An error occurred while installing json (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.4.6'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: okay no--now I get compilation failures. I'll send you the files.

Comment: I went with the nuclear option: I commented out everything in the Gemfile and started adding gems one-by-one, running bundle install between them.  I didn't write the original code and I've come to believe that the gem dependencies were copy-pasted from elsewhere. Anyway, I've discovered that the culprit is the "chefspec" gem. To make things a little more interesting, bundle install does not fail if there's already a Gemfile.lock.

Comment: Interesting, good discovery. In my personal experience, Chef has been a mess due to regressive code and outdated version dependencies. I changed from Chef to Ansible.